# Thevenin voltage across current source

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

I got a weird question in a circuits analysis test today that asked for the thevenin equivalent across a current source and not a load. Is it valid to ask for the thevenin equivalent across a current source? If so, do you leave or take out the source when calculating the thevenin voltage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What, I think, is being asked is for you to find the Thevenin equivalent of the circuit *seen* by the current source.

In other words, *remove* the current source and then find:

(1) the open circuit voltage across the port where the current source was formally connected

(2) the equivalent resistance looking into that port.

For example, consider the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f79clF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The Thevenin equivalent *across* (or *seen* by) the current source is

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPoFQw.png)</sup>

where

\$R_{th} = R_1||R_2 \$

\$V_{th} = V_1 \dfrac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2} \$

Comment: But if we connect the thevenin equivalent circuit to the current source, wouldn't that be an illegal configuration since the current source may conflict with the voltage source?

Comment: No, it is a permissive configuration

Comment: @Chuz thanks you're right, I was confusing it with something else.

Answer (score 2):

This is really weird question and need some flexible thinking. At first you know that the ideal current source always keep the same current in the external loop.

If such current source is connected without load, it is actually connected to the infinite resistance load.

So, the Thevenin equivalent will consists by an voltage source with infinite voltage, connected with resistor with infinite resistance.

In reality such an source will rise its voltage to values that will cause the breakdown and electrical arc with the given current (even in vacuum). That is why the current sources must always have some load, lower than infinity.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fz4dCn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This just the Norton to Thevenin transformation in the limit as Rth goes to infinity:  \$V_{th} = I_N \cdot R_{th}\$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert an ideal independent current source to its equivalent Thevenin circuit, it must be represented as a Norton circuit.

[image: Norton circuit of ideal independent current source]

Open-circuit voltage: For A and B being unconnected, no current flows in the circuit. The internal impedance of the current source is infinite (open circuit) so the open-circuit voltage, \$V_{OC}\$, that is the voltage of A with respect to B is undetermined.\begin{align*}V_{OC}&=I_RR\cr&=0\times\infty\cr&=\textrm{NaN}\;\textrm{(undetermined)}\end{align*}

Short-circuit current: For A and B being short-circuited, the short-circuit current, \$I_{SC}\$, that is the current from A to B, is equal to the current of the independent current source,\begin{equation*}I_{SC}=I\end{equation*}

Now we can build its equivalent Thevenin circuit. The voltage of the ideal independent voltage source is the open circuit voltage of its Norton counterpart,\begin{align*}V&=V_{OC}\cr&=\textrm{NaN}\;\textrm{(undetermined)}\end{align*}
Its impedance is the impedance of its Norton counterpart, \$R=\infty\$.

[image: Thevenin circuit of ideal independent current source]

Open-circuit voltage: For A and B being unconnected, there is no source which can determine the open-circuit voltage, \$V_{OC}\$, that is the voltage of A with respect to B. So it is undetermined.\begin{align*}V_{OC}&=\textrm{NaN}\;\textrm{(undetermined)}\end{align*}

Short-circuit current: For A and B being short-circuited, there is no source to determine the short-circuit current, \$I_{SC}\$, that is the current from A to B, so it is zero,\begin{equation*}I_{SC}=0\end{equation*}

We can see that the short-circuit current of the Norton circuit (of the ideal independent current source), that is \$I\$, is different from the short-circuit of its Thevenin equivalent, that is \$0\$. It implies that an ideal independent current source has no equivalent Thevenin circuit. You can not convert an ideal independent current source to a Thevenin circuit.

Comment: In the Thevenin circuit, there is no source to determine the short-circuit current, so it can be undetermined.(not zero) but still it is not equal to the short-circuit current of its Norton counterpart, the Norton circuit of an ideal independent current source which is equal to I, so still there is no equivalent Thevenin circuit of an ideal independent current source.