# Thevenin Equivalent Circuit of Ideal Independent Current Source

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-source, thevenin, voltage-source, norton

This is dual to <[Norton Equivalent Circuit of Ideal Independent Voltage Source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/515958/norton-equivalent-circuit-of-ideal-independent-voltage-source)>. I have wrote it to answer a problem <[click here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84923/thevenin-voltage-across-current-source/515772#515772)> but I need to make it independent which requires corrections, verifications, comments, etc. In order to follow Norton to Thevenin convertion procedure the ideal independent current source to be converted is represented as a Norton circuit.

[image]

Norton open-circuit voltage: For A and B being disconnected, no current flows in the circuit. The internal impedance of the current source is infinite (open circuit) so the open-circuit voltage, \$^{NO}V_{OC}\$, the voltage of A with respect to B is undetermined.\begin{align*}^{NO}V_{OC}&=I_RR\cr&=0\times\infty\cr&=\textrm{NaN}\;\textrm{(undetermined)}\end{align*}

Norton short-circuit current: For A and B being short-circuited, the short-circuit current, \$^{NO}I_{SC}\$, the current from A to B, is equal to the current of the independent current source,\begin{equation*}^{NO}I_{SC}=I\end{equation*}

Then we can construct its equivalent Thevenin circuit. The voltage of the ideal independent voltage source of a Thevenin circuit is the open circuit voltage of its Norton counterpart,\begin{align*}V&=^{NO}V_{OC}\cr&=\textrm{NaN}\;\textrm{(undetermined)}\end{align*}
Its impedance is the impedance of its Norton counterpart, \$R=\infty\$.
[image]

Thevenin open-circuit voltage: For A and B being open-circuited, there is no source which determines the open-circuit voltage, \$^{TH}V_{OC}\$, the voltage of A with respect to B. So it is undetermined.\begin{align*}^{TH}V_{OC}&=\textrm{NaN}\;\textrm{(undetermined)}\end{align*}

Thevenin short-circuit current: For A and B being short-circuited, there is no source to determine the short-circuit current, \$^{TH}I_{SC}\$, the current from A to B, so it is zero or undetermined,\begin{equation*}^{TH}I_{SC}=0\;\textrm{or}\;^{TH}I_{SC}=\textrm{NaN}\end{equation*}

The Norton short-circuit current (representing an ideal independent current source), \$^{TH}I_{SC}=I\$, is different from the short-circuit of its Thevenin equivalent, \$^{TH}I_{SC}=0\$ or \$^{TH}I_{SC}=\textrm{NaN}\$. It implies that an ideal independent current source has no equivalent Thevenin circuit. So I can not convert an ideal independent current source to a Thevenin circuit. I need corrections, verifications, comments, etc.

Comment: This site is for answering specific questions, not proofreading.

Comment: Notation is very poor.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is right. the only thing you need to consider is the definition of an ideal DC current source and that is a source that regardless of the voltage between its terminals, its current is constant. with this definition you can't replace them with each other.
Nevertheless, Thevenin and Norton equivalents are methods for simplify complicated circuits and not for replacing a single source with another.
It worth mentioning that in the real world there are no ideal sources, so this would never happen.